# How can I access the map in Sekiro pc version?

Tags: sekiro-shadows-die-twice

I was watching a video on YouTube about Sekiro: Shadows Die Twice, and saw the player use a map during the game on his ps4. I play Sekiro on my pc. I searched through the inventory and checked the key bindings and pressed every key on my keyboard, but I didn't find anything. 
How can I access the map?

I'm in the Hirata Estate now, and have not crossed the Ashina castle gate. Should I proceed further into the game to get access to the map?

There are so many places to access with the hook, but this map wasn't that detailed. I just wanna make sure that I explore every playable area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "level map" in the conventional sense in Sekiro. It is possible that the player you watched edited a map into the video or opened it in another tab.

However, there is a map called the "Antique Map" that can be accessed by pressing the "Y" or triangle button on the controller while you are in the travel screen. On PC, the default key to open this map is <kbd>F</kbd>. Look in the bottom right hand corner of the travel screen image to see the tooltip. I have included a spoilered picture of both the travel screen and map below.

> [image: Travel Screen]
>  [image: Antique Map]

Note: The Antique Map does not start with all of the areas named. The area names are filled in as they are discovered.